# Which of two partials is renderd?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I'm trying to understand foobar rails code and encountered following.
There is controller A which inherits from controller B (A < B). And both of them don't have "index" method, but B has view "app/views/B/index.rhtml.erb" which will be rendered on that action from A controller. In that view there is line:

```
render(:partial => "find")
```

But there are two files: "app/views/A/_find.rhtml.erb" and "app/views/B/_find.rjs"
And i can't understand which would be rendered if index was called from A controller.
Further more "app/views/B/_find.rjs" has line:

```
page.replace_html(:contentBody, :partial => "find")
```

And i have no idea what is rendered here.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think , it depends on wich controller the user see, and that behavior is defined by the route system (config/routes.rb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application will only render the `rjs` files if a script was requested (usually through an AJAX request). If the user accesses your index action normally (i.e. a request for HTML using a browser), your app will render `index.rhtml.erb` to produce the HTML response, which will in turn render `_find.rhtml.erb`. If some part of your page is requesting a script, then `_find.rjs` will be rendered (which actually just produces a javascript response behind the scenes). In this case, `_find.rjs` actually uses the HTML partial `_find.rhtml.erb` in the call to `replace_html` to replace part of the page.

BTW, you seem to be using an older version of Rails as `rhtml` and `rjs` are no longer used. I'd suggest working with a newer version.

Comment: Yes that's Rails 2.3.5. And in the moment i don't have a resource to switch entire application to Rails 3.

Comment: Thanks! It's gotten much clearer now. If i got you right then if i'm trying to reach 'application.com/A/index' i get index.rhtml.erb with _find.rhtml.erb as a partial.